# How to implement inheritance with Java-8?

Tags: java-8

I have a program with `AddService` class which is implementing `IService` interface as follows:

**IService.java**

```
public interface IService {

    Integer add(int x, int y);
}
```

**AddService.java**

```
import com.test.service.IService;

public class AddService implements IService {

    @Override
    public Integer add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Above code compiles and run fine, but as soon as I change above implementation using `Java-8` provided `BiFunction` as below, IDE starts complaining at compile time.

**IService.java**

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public interface IService {

    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add( x, y);
}
```

**AddService.java**

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import com.test.service.IService;

public class AddService implements IService {

    @Override
    public BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add = (x, y) -> {
        return x + y;
    };

}
```

Any idea how I can resolve the error and make my program run?

Comment: `add` is a (implicit) `static final` field in the interface and there is no inheritance here.

Comment: Java 8 does not change how you write classes. You may use `(x, y) -> x + y` in place of your `IService` implementation though (not writing a class at all)

Comment: @Tom: changing the add to `add(x,y)` is giving compile time error as - "x can not be resloved", any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Look what you wrote here `add(int x, int y)` and what you did here `add( x, y)`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Inheritance in Java 8 is implemented the same way as it is done in previous versions. You posted a working version, then, before asking us about why the changes don’t work, explain why you did these changes and what you want to achieve with them.

Comment: @Tom Changing `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add(int x, int y);` in interface forcing me to specify datatype in implementaion class as well like `@Override
 public BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
 }`

Comment: ```BiFunction``` acts as a replacement for ```IService```. The second ```IService``` you define, has a function ```add``` that returns a ```BiFuction```, which is different in intent from the first ```IService```. You also probably want to use ```IntBinaryOperator``` to avoid boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda expressions enable you to express *code* as *data*.  You could write:

```
IService addService = (x, y) -> x + y;
```

which declares a *variable* `addService` that implements `IService`.  Better, get rid of `IService` and use `IntBinaryOperator`:

```
IntBinaryOperator add = (x, y) -> x + y;
IntBinaryOperator subtract = (x, y) -> x - y;
...
```

and use `add` where you would have otherwise used `new AddService()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `IService` is creates for a reason and the actual implementations are non trivial, I would write a non-trival implementation like this.

```
public interface IService {
    int op(int x, int y);
}

public enum OpService implements IService {
    ADD {
        @Override
        public int op(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    },
    MINUS {
        @Override
        public int op(int x, int y) {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntBinaryOperator add = OpService.ADD::op;
        IntBinaryOperator minus = OpService.MINUS::op;

        System.out.println(add.applyAsInt(2, 3));
    }
}
```

prints

```
5
```

However, if all you want to do is add two numbers together I would just use `+`

Comment: Really? This is how you would write this? Declaring an interface which you don’t use, implementing it via an `enum`, just for creating method reference out of it? How about implementing `IntBinaryOperator` in the first place rather than `IService`? Or just creating two static methods for the method references, without the obsolete interface and enum?

Comment: @Holger in this trivial case, you can drop most of the code, I agree. Brian's solution is enough.   However, assuming the `IService` was created for a reason, and the example is non trivial, this is the pattern I have used.

Comment: @Holger if you just want to add two number together, I wouldn't use lambdas, I would use `+`

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. Assume you have a method like

```
public void someMethod(IService addService) {
    System.out.println(addService.add(2, 4));
}
```

With Java 8, you're now allowed to call that method like

```
public void anotherMethod() {
    someMethod((x, y) -> x + y);
}
```

instead of having to properly implement `IService` and do something like

```
public void anotherMethod() {
    someMethod(new AddService());
}
```

A lambda can serve as implementation to all functional interfaces. The `BiFunction` interface exists so that you don't even have to add the `IService` interface. You could instead just do

```
public void someMethod2(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addService) {
    System.out.println(addService.apply(2, 4));
}

public void anotherMethod() {
    someMethod((x, y) -> x + y);
}
```

and it would still work. The identical lamda will this time be treated as `BiFunction` instead of `IService`.